# Assigning values to some specific variables using dplyr or purrr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to assign the same value of other present variable to some missing data, but in a `dplyr` or `tidyverse` way.

For instance, this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(13, 14, 15, 16, 17), 
                 name = c("Bob", "Alice", "Joe", "Bob", "Alice"), 
                 year = c("2016", "2017", "2005", NA, NA))

> df
  id  name year
1 13   Bob 2016
2 14 Alice 2017
3 15   Joe 2005
4 16   Bob <NA>
5 17 Alice <NA>
```

I would like to assign value "2016" to "Bob" in line 4. 
I can do this using `which` function:

```
df[which(df$name == "Bob"),]$year = "2016"
```

But, how to do this with `dplyr`, `purrr`, or whatever other package from `tidyverse`?

Comment: Consider the [`tinyverse`](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/a574bf/tinyverse_lightweight_is_the_right_weight/) way with `base` package using `ave`: `df$year <- with(df, ave(year, name, FUN=function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fill` from the tidyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%

  # within each name, fill missing years (default direction is downwards)
  group_by(name) %>%
  fill(year) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # sort rows by original order
  arrange(id)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id name  year 
  <dbl> <fct> <fct>
1    13 Bob   2016 
2    14 Alice 2017 
3    15 Joe   2005 
4    16 Bob   2016 
5    17 Alice 2017
```